# Jquery - multiple selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the below code so it doesn't let my page reload in every submit.

Can I modify it so instead of the submit selector I use the `name="value"` and put multiple values?

I need that because I have submit buttons that are `type="image"` so I cannot use the submit selector.

e.g. if I have buttons with names={nam1, nam2, nam3}
how do I change this code in order to get the page not refreshed when they are clicked?

```
$(".class123").click(function() {
  var keyValues = {
    pid : $(this).parent().find('input[name="pid"]').val(),
    };
      $.post('help_scripts/cart_functions.php', keyValues, function(rsp) {
       // make your php script return some xml or json that gives the result
       // rsp will be the response
       });
         return false;
         // so the page doesn't POST
 });
```

In this line  - WHICH I NEED TO HAVE -

```
pid : $(this).parent().find('input[name="pid"]').val(),
```

pid is the name and id of my 1st button... How do I add more keyvalues here?

Answer (score 4):

I think you can just do comma seperated selectors:

```
$(':submit').click(function() {
  var keyValues = {
    pid : $('input[name="nam1"],input[name="nam2"],input[name="nam3"]').val(),
    };
      $.post('help_scripts/cart_functions.php', keyValues, function(rsp) {
       // make your php script return some xml or json that gives the result
       // rsp will be the response
       });
         return false;
         // so the page doesn't POST
 });
```

http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

That said, it might make more sense to assign a css class to all buttons you want to have this functionality or just select all buttons.

Button selector:

```
$(":button")
```

Class selector:

```
$(".SubmitButton")
```

Comment: class sounds better... and how do I add more keyValues in the code? I saw the comma separated names but <pid> there is the name of my 1st button... I will modify my post a bit to express what I need if I use class selector.

Comment: "how do I add more keyValues in the code?" -- `var keyValues = {nam1:$(input[name="nam1").val(), nam2:$(input[name="nam2").val()...etc }`

Comment: also, when defining keyValues, get rid of the trailing comma if nothing follows it. IE6 (and maybe 7) will choke on it, if you care about browser compatibility.

Comment: @daybreaker ok... it did the trick... but it has a problem... when I press nam2=delete button which deletes an item, it does delete it but it needs the page to refresh to remove it. Is there a fix so when the delete button is pressed the item gets deleted immediately? thank you

Comment: I guess you could add another class that hides the data you want to disappear.

Comment: I will start another thread because the title here is not indicating what I need now. Thank you all for helping me on this one.

Comment: No problem, if my answer solved your problem feel free to accept it by clicking the outline of the checkmark in the top left corner.

Answer (score 0):

Change type submit to just a plain ole vanilla `<button>`.